# Navigation between pages like in IE10

Tags: windows-8

I'm developing metro-style app for Windows 8. Currently I use buttons with arrows for navigation in my app but I want to handle gestures (just like in IE for changing pages, from left to right). How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is not too complicated, is `FlipView` an option for you?

MSDN References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465425.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211711.aspx